# HLOOKUP/VLOOKUP to replace nested IF-functions

Tags: excel

I have the following Excel spreadsheet:

```
        A             B             C                D             E
1                    Sale 1        Sale 2         Sale 3
2    Product A         0             0              400          Sale 3
3    Product B         0             0              300          Sale 3
4    Product C         0            200               0          Sale 2
5    Product D        800            0                0          Sale 1
```

In **Columns B:D** you can see the Sales for each product.

In **Column E** I want to show in which Sale the product was sold.
Therefore, the Sale which is `<> 0` should be shown.

I used the following formula so far:

```
=IF(B3<>0,B$2,WENN(C3<>0,C$2,WENN(D3<>0,D$2)))
```

This formula works in the upper case quite well but in my orignal example there are much more sales which would expand this formula massively.
Is there a way to shorten the formula so it is not necessary to use so many nested IF-functions?

Maybe somethling like a HLOOKUP with a value `<> 0` criteria?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following formula should be helpful:

```
=INDEX($B$1:$D$1,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX($B2:$D2<>0,),0))
```

Drag/Copy down as required.

See image for reference:

[image]

Comment: Hi Mrig, thanks for the answer. It works perfectly. Is it actually also possilbe to add another criteria to this formula. For example something like this: =INDEX($B$1:$D$1,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(AND($B2:$D2<>0;$B2:$D2<>""),),0))

Comment: @Michi - Hi, use can use this formula for multiple conditions: `=INDEX($B$1:$D$1,MATCH(1,INDEX(($B2:$D2<>0)*($B2:$D2<>""),),0))`